# get Error in Entity Framework and SQL Server Compact edition database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I use VS2010, Entity Framework and a SQL Server Compact edition database. I use this connection string:

```
<add name="ConnNew" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Code.Model1.csdl|res://*/Code.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Code.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.sdf&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

It's working in my system. but after setup application in other system, it's not working and get this error:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. if you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. if you click quit. the application will close immediately.
>
> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
>
> Details:
>   See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ******* *Exception Text* *********
>   System.ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

Comment: You're being unclear - the **connection string** clearly says **SQL Server Compact Edition** (`provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5` and `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.sdf`) while you insist on SQL Server "Local" database (what exactly do you mean by "Local" database?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your application references the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` assembly and it is set to copy the assembly locally as well

Check the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on how to deploy the SQL Server CE 3.5 Database

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll. Where do I find and add it? I use setup in VS2010

Comment: i not use SQL Server Compact! I use SQL Local Database (Local DataBase in VS2010)

Comment: The connection string you mentioned includes provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;